# How to get blog slug after onclick in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working in Reactjs and i am working in nextjs,Right now i am trying to get "slug" value after click on blog,But right now i am getting undefined as value,I tried with following code

```
<h4 onClick={mainFunction}>{post.title}</h4>  

const mainFunction = (e) => {
    //alert(`So your name is `);
    const value = e.target.value;
    alert('value is'+ value);
  };
```

Comment: you mean `e.target.innerText` ?

Comment: @KcH its working but there maybe same blog name so can you tell me that how can we use id instead of slug ? means i want to add any attribute to <h4> tag ( blog id as custom attribute) so i want to get that id after click on that blog,Hope you can understand

Comment: you mean, you want to get the attributes of the element ? you can use `e.target.{id / whatever_the_attribute}` ..... hope I understood it correctly

Comment: @KcH How can i add/use attribute in <h4> tag ? can you explain this please

Comment: you can do it by having data attributes as well as `<h4 id="some_id" data-att1="some_data" onClick={mainFunction}>{post.title}</h4>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass slug while calling the mainFunction on click

```
<h4 onClick={() => mainFunction(post.slug)}>{post.title}</h4>  

const mainFunction = (slug) => {
  //alert(`So your name is `);
  alert('value is'+ slug);
};
```